# between() выбираем значения между определенными значениями Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Вот запрос:

`self::find()->where(["DATE BETWEEN 1492136083 AND 1494791282"])->all();`

в базе есть несколько полей у которых date в промежутке двух значении, но интерпретатор выдает ошибку

```
    Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'Operator 'DATE BETWEEN 1492136083 AND 1494791282' requires two operands.' 

in /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php:1430

Stack trace:
#0 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php(1057): yii\db\QueryBuilder->buildSimpleCondition('DATE BETWEEN 14...', Array, Array)
#1 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php(861): yii\db\QueryBuilder->buildCondition(Array, Array)
#2 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php(100): yii\db\QueryBuilder->buildWhere(Array, Array)
#3 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php(319): yii\db\QueryBuilder->build(Object(yii\db\Query))
#4 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(213): yii\db\ActiveQuery->createCommand(Object(yii\db\Connection))
#5 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php(133): yii\db\Query->all(NULL)
#6 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/models/ResultInteriew.php(55): yii\db\ActiveQuery->all()
#7 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/controllers/SiteController.php(109): app\models\ResultInteriew::get_list_result('1492136083', '1494791282')
#8 [internal function]: app\controllers\SiteController->actionViewinfo()
#9 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#11 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('viewinfo', Array)
#12 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/viewinfo', Array)
#13 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#14 /home/m/melis20649/Info/public_html/web/index.php(11): yii\base\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было так

```
self::find()->where(['between', 'date', "1492136083", "1494791282"])->all();
```